# Unable to add account on android 6.0.1

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, google-account

I have an old android tablet - Asus/Google Nexus 7 (2013) - which I would like to use with Touch Portal. The tablet was factory reset several years ago and has, I believe, the latest release of Android (6.0.1) that was officially released for it.

I've tried a couple of times to get signed in to my Google account on the device. It prompts me for my username and password and then appears to hang - currently over 24 hours as I write this.

I have a feeling that this is caused by 2 factor authentication which I have enabled on my account - the default of which is a security key, specifically a Yubico Yubikey 5 NFC.

I once saw a message about using a security key so I have attempted to use it via USB and NFC. When I tried this last time via NFC, I saw a new login in my Google Account at the same time but the screen still hangs.

I'm not prepared yet to disable 2 factor authentication (albeit temporarily) quite yet but may consider it if there really are no other options.

[image: Screenshot of tablet showing greyed out screen and no prompt]

**UPDATE** Here's the confirmation that my Yubikey was used during the attempt to login despite nothing showing on screen prompting such action and nothing happening afterwards.

[image: Yubikey usage Nexus 7]

Comment: What does your "recent Google activities" at https://myaccount.google.com show?

Comment: @Robert It's not showing anything related to the login and I'm unable to find it again now!

Comment: I would assume that your main problem is that the installed Google services have not yet updated itself. Make sure the tablet is always on and connected to a Wifi with full Internet access and wait a few hours (up to a day). Usually google services should install latest update.

Comment: And... I can't update them via Play Store unless I add an account!

Comment: As far as I know the play services update themselves independently of a logged in Google user. The only problem is that you can't trigger the update manually instead you have to wait that it happens automatically.

Comment: Okay, I'll leave it a bit then and see if it updates. It's currently on Version 8.1.22 (2959233-436). My Pixle 5 is on Version 21.02.14 (150400-352619232)

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @Robert who pointed me in the right direction.

Unfortunately Google Play services didn't update itself automatically even though it had been on for a couple of days. So... I resorted to downloading a recent version from apkmirror, found the right version for the 2013 Asus Nexus 7 (armeabi-v7a, Android 6.0+, nodpi).

It took a minute or so to install but it was successful, after which I attempted to login again. This time, after entering my password, I was prompted to choose how I wanted to use my security key to login. Chose NFC, and I'm in.